# Sub tables MySQL

Tags: mysql

I’m wondering if I could create a table inside a table in MySQL?, I have a database called restaurants and in restaurants there is a table for each of the restaurants eg, nandos, frankie and bennies, so on and so on. Would it be possible to create a sub-table sort of thing for the items/menu and then another sub-table for the staff working there and then another for order history? If so how would I go about doing this? Any help would be great ask any questions if needed as I’m not very good at explaining haha.

Comment: I don't necessarily see anything wrong/limiting about just having a single table for restaurants.  Can you add some sample data to your question?

Comment: I’ve kind of said the question wrong, my schema is called FoodPlace (Example business name) and the table inside is called restaurants, so inside restaurants I would like to have each individual restaurant include the following sub tables; order history, staff and menu, but because it’s in one table I couldn’t for example add the menu for nandos in restaurants because I have a primary key called restaurantid so if I did have order history or so in the restaurants table it would act as another restaurant? So it was purely just to know if I could make restaurants table a sort of sub database.

Comment: If u can message me on Twitter ‘@‘ andrewcrossan11 I can send you the screenshot I’ve took of the layout of the database and a slightly better explanation, I would post on this but apparently I don’t have enough rep

Comment: MySQL does not have “sub tables”. Use appropriate RA relationships and joins. The association is made by using a FK relating to the ‘parent’ relationship.

Comment: See https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561 , https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-parent-child-relationship-in-mysql  , https://www.calebcurry.com/parent-child-tables/  etc. and other SQL tutorials for how achieve the desired the modeling. The same concept holds to using *one* table for all the different restaurants as “restaurant” itself can be viewed as a ‘parent’ of the related first-order data.

Comment: We don't *message* people here. If your question cannot be asked and answered here, it shouldn't be asked here. You should find a good SQL tutorial to learn about basic database design, which can provide you with the knowledge needed for this sort of task.

Comment: Could probably relate my knowledge of on here to my lack of reputation aswell

Answer (score 0):

I dont think we have sub tables. but from your problem sounds like a normal relationship ?

```
create table restaurant as 
select 1 AS restaurant_ID, 'Nandos' AS restaurant_name
union
select 2, 'Frankie';

create table staff as
select 1 AS staff_ID, 'Andrew' AS staff_name
union
select 2, 'Crossan';

create table menu as
select 1 AS menu_ID, 'Burger' AS menu_name
union
select 2, 'Sandwich';

create table order_history as
select 1 AS order_ID, 1 AS restaurant_ID, 1 AS staff_ID, 1 AS menu_ID, 1 AS qty, 12 AS price # 1 qty of Burger served by Andrew on Nandos restaurant
union
select 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 8; #3 qty of Sandwich served by Andrew on Nandos restaurant
```

now try selecting from order_history joining other tables